# Low Audio Volume Elementary OS 5.1.3 Hera

Tags: release-hera, sound

the sound of the system is low compared to other operating systems, I checked in settings and the audio is 100%, can someone help me, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try set the volume via alsamixer.

```
alsamixer
```

If you have more than one audiocard in your computer make sure to switch it by hitting F6.
You could also try "PulseAudio Volume Control", which are available in appcenter.

regards