# Elementary OS Hera not detecting my speakers

Tags: release-hera, audio

I connected my speakers to 3.5mm port in the back of my pc(on the motherboard) and OS doesn't detect them. I went to "Sound" settings and there were only my headphones and HDMI output because my monitor has speakers.

Note that I just installed Elementary OS today and haven't played around with drivers or anything.

How do I detect my newly connected speakers?

I'm using Hera 5.1.3

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I just plug out my headphones when I want to use speakers and it automatically switches to speakers, and when I want to use headphones, I just plug them back in.

Answer (score 0):

The may be detected, but muted on the system.
You may check this question and its answer, it may help your problem: [Low Audio Volume Elementary OS 5.1.3 Hera](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/24008/low-audio-volume-elementary-os-5-1-3-hera/24009#24009)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but if I can't see them in my Sound settings, how can I make them default device over headphones? I don't want  to play them both in the same time.